# What does it mean to "preconcat" a matrix in Android?

Tags: android, view, canvas

In reviewing: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

I'm wondering

translate(): "preconcat the current matrix with the specified translation" -- what does this mean?

I can't find a good definition of "preconcat" anywhere on the internet! The only place I can find it is in the Android Source - I'm starting to wonder if they made it up? :)

I'm familiar with "concat" or concatenate, which is to append to, so what is a pre-concat?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When working with matrices, the word concatenation refers to multiplication.

Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, there is a separate word for backwards multiplication.
Pre-concatenating `a` to `b` means setting `a = b × a`.  (As opposed to `a = a × b`, which will give a different matrix)

Comment: Thank you. My question was in the context of the Android Canvas however and I'm having a hard time making the connection between the canvas and the matrix?

Comment: @Brad: The canvas maintains a transform matrix; `translate` manipulates it.

Comment: The canvas maintains a matrix and the canvas is manipulated by methods which are well defined in OpenGL. A great source of relevant definitions is: http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Theory

Answer (score -1):

It just another example Google and their development absue words and abbriviations in the code.If I run the authorithy i will impose a fine on this.Basicaly it means multiply the existing matrix from the right side,and because in vector transformation the one on the right side gets moved first so it is a "pre-".For example if you want to scale the image and move to another location you should type:

```
    mCanvas.translate(tx,ty);
    mCanvas.scale(sx,sy);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mPaint);
```

It is excatly in reverse order of common sense logic.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but it isn't only Android which uses this convention, as the Windows Drawing2D and HTML Canvas APIs also work in the same way (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149432)). My guess is that they're all ultimately based on OpenGL.